# Can't install modules via pip

Tags: python, pip, dronekit

I can't install MAVProxy module via pip. The error appears which shows:

[image]

I have tried to install with sudo -H flag but the error always appears and I can't install anything with pip.

Comment: Follow the  documentation  : http://ardupilot.github.io/MAVProxy/html/getting_started/download_and_installation.html

Comment: I have tried this link but the error still appears and I can't install MAVProxy.

Comment: There should be be a compiler error above the message from your question. Usually it complaint about a missing `.h` file.

Answer (score 1):

All I did I install MAVProxy using

```
pip2.7 install MAVProxy
```

and it worked.

Comment: You were trying to install 3.5 earlier